# Telephone Dial Program Converting Letters to Card Suits Instead of Numbers

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a program in which a user can enter a telephone number using either letters or numbers, and if they use letters, it should convert them to their corresponding number on a telephone keypad. However, when the letters are converted, instead of becoming numbers, they become card suit symbols, like clubs, hearts, and spades. Not sure why this is happening. Here is the function in which the converting is supposed to happen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int read_dials(char &digit1, char &digit2, char &digit3, char &digit4, char &digit5, char &digit6, char &digit7, char &digit8);
int todigit(char &digit);
void acknowledge_call(char digit1, char digit2, char digit3, char digit4, char digit5, char digit6, char digit7, char digit8);


int todigit(char &digit)
{
    int errorCode = 0;

    switch (digit)
    {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
            digit = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F':
        case 'd':
        case 'e':
        case 'f':
            digit = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 'G':
        case 'H':
        case 'I':
        case 'g':
        case 'h':
        case 'i':
            digit = 4;
            break;
        case 5:
        case 'J':
        case 'K':
        case 'L':
        case 'j':
        case 'k':
        case 'l':
            digit = 5;
            break;
        case 6:
        case 'M':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
        case 'm':
        case 'n':
        case 'o':
            digit = 6;
            break;
        case 7:
        case 'P':
        case 'Q':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
        case 'p':
        case 'q':
        case 'r':
        case 's':
            digit = 7;
            break;
        case 8:
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
        case 'V':
        case 't':
        case 'u':
        case 'v':
            digit = 8;
            break;
        case 9:
        case 'W':
        case 'X':
        case 'Y':
        case 'Z':
        case 'w':
        case 'x':
        case 'y':
        case 'z':
            digit = 9;
            break;
    }
    // nice size switch statemwent

    return errorCode;
}
```

Here is the function for printing the phone number:

```
void acknowledge_call(char digit1, char digit2, char digit3, char digit4, char digit5, char digit6, char digit7, char digit8)
{
    cout << "Phone Number Dialed: " << digit1 << digit2 << digit3 << digit4 << digit5 << digit6 << digit7 << digit8;
}
```

Comment: How are you printing the numbers? Printing numbers doesn't normally result in card suits, so you must be printing them in an unusual manner.

Comment: Edited the post to show the function I'm using to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of char datatype just assign the digit to an integer variable or assign 48+digit to the char value which assigns the ASCII value 48+1=49 i.e.,, char '1'.

When you write

```
char ch = 'A';
```

you're setting the value of ch to the number your compiler uses to represent the character 'A'. That's usually the ASCII code for 'A' which is 65.

Like any numeric type, you can initialize it with an ordinary number which gives the same result:

```
char ch = 65;
```

In your case, you are trying to assign the char variable with the values 2,3,...9 values which in turn displays the relative ASCII value which might be displayed differently on different output streams.

Refer to the following link for more information on ASCII codes:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by putting single apostrophes on either side of the numbers that I was converting them to.

For example:

```
digit = '2';
```

instead of

```
digit = 2;
```